# Uso correcto de la meta tag h1 h2 SEO

Tags: html5, optimización, seo

> La mayor parte de las **meta tag** nos basamos a la importancia más al *SEO* **Google**, pero será amigable también para estos buscadores **Bing MSN, DMOZ, Yahoo.**

Buscando en google he tomado las primeras cuatro páginas de los primeros resultados estudiando su estructura SEO.

Para sorpresa me encontré tres tipos de títulos en la misma página.

```
<title>Agencia Multimedia móviles iPhone Android.</title>
<meta name="title" content="Agencia Multimedia móviles iPhone Android.">
<meta property="og:title" content="Agencia Multimedia móviles iPhone Android.">
```

Encontré cuatro tipo de **meta description** en la misma página para sorpresa una de ella en idioma inglés.

```
<meta name="description" lang="en" content="Agency Multimedia iPhone Android Mobile.">
<meta content="Agencia Multimedia móviles iPhone Android." name="description" content="Agencia Multimedia móviles iPhone Android.">
<meta itemprop="description">
<meta property="og:description" content="Agencia Multimedia móviles iPhone Android.">
```

**Las URL canónicas** note que muestra en el mismo sitio dos especificaciones iguales.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://blog.example.com/dresses/green-dresses-are-awesome" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://blog.example.com/dresses/green-dresses-are-awesome">
```

Como otros tipos de meta tag muy relevantes e interesantes, todo esto tomado de las primeras cuatro páginas de los primeros resultados.

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#009587">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#009587">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/themes/dejabu/images/og_logo.png">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Proun New Media Agency">
<meta name="author" content="Multi Estudio">
<meta name="revisit-after" content="10-days">
<meta name="robots" content="all/index/follow">
<meta content="global" name="distribution">
<meta name="language" content="spanish">
<meta name="copyright" content="Copyright © 2014 Multi Studio All rights reserved.">
```

**Mi pregunta:**

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre `name="og:title" name="DC.title"`?

¿De todas los meta tag mencionados como hacerles entender a los principales buscadores **Google, Bing MSN, DMOZ, Yahoo**?

La importancia de las etiquetas **h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6** ¿Cuantas h1 se pueden repetir en la misma página al igual de las otras etiquetas?

¿El usó de robots.txt?

Comment: Me parece una pregunta muy interesante. Estaré al tanto sobre ella.

Comment: Estas preguntas sobre SEO están permitidos en SOes?

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas: [Directrices de Google para webmasters](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769/?hl=es) y [Crear un archivo robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=es&ref_topic=6061961)

Comment: @aldanux Realmente está directamente relacionado con el desarrollo web. Además, esta pregunta está bien documentada y por lo que parece son preguntas bastante concretas. Yo creo que esta pregunta si que cumpliría con los canones de SOes. Sin embargo, si no estas seguro, podrías poner una pregunta en meta para salir de dudas.

Comment: @Error404 - Lo haré pero se que en SOen no esta permitido (off topic)

Comment: @aldanux No lo sabía. Estaré al tanto de todas maneras.

Comment: @aldanux Esta pregunta no está permitida? Observe unas preguntas sobre seo por ende me arriesgué a preguntar? Existe también una etiqueta tags de seo aquí? Lo único que no es relevante creo es la palabra **SEO** pero la mayor parte del contenido en realidad todo el contenido se basa a programación a etiquetas básicas de la estructura **HTML** si no estoy mal.

Comment: @Josues - No lo se si esta permitido o no aquí... hay referencia en meta pero no me quedo claro... He preguntado a un moderador... pero no he votado aún para cerrar ni te he votado negativo...

Comment: Pues se supone que se deben preguntar en http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/     pero no sé si haya para Español

Comment: Con respecto a las preguntas que se hacen acá, pienso que hay varias que con una búsqueda simple en google se sabrían. Sin embargo `name="og:XXX" y DC.XXX` hacen referencia para diferentes formas de hacer ver su página, og = open graph, dc = dublin core.  puede leer más del tema en http://ogp.me/ y   en   http://www.metatags.org/dublin_core_metadata_element_set

Comment: @Shaz Me perdí completamente? La pregunta tenía 4 votos y ahora solo 1 me base a las estructuras que tenían las primeras 4 páginas en los primeros resultados en Google, pero podría añadir más pregunta? Creo que sería igual como una muy buena referencia para los demás, claro que todo sobre maquetación seo, se integra más preguntas, pero tomando ejemplo de las primeras paginas en google se toma como una buena maquetación o por lo menos una buena estructura **SEO** bueno eso pienso perdon si estoy mal. Pero si no es bienvenida la pregunta decime, para eliminarla.

Comment: En este punto no sabría decirte si la pregunta es bienvenida o no, eso nos lo podría indicar alguno de los moderadores. Para mí está bien, tal vez un poco amplia.

Comment: Son cuatro preguntas en la misma publicación. Las respuestas están basadas en opiniones. No parece que encaje en el formato del SOes.

Comment: @toledano La respuestas están basadas a opiniones? Mmm... No veo que se sabe a opiniones la primera se basaba si pero bueno ya la sustituí, pero el resto son preguntas claves perdón si estoy mal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aún conservo algunos apuntes sobre `SEO`, que quiero compartir algunos de ellos, ya que se podría extender bastante este temario.

Aunque el trabajo de un correcto posicionamiento `SEO` se basa en muchos puntos, veamos algunos ejemplos a tu pregunta, uno de los importantes es la **estructura** y el **contenido** de la web.

Veamos que tampoco es complicado diseñar una página web orientado al posicionamiento `SEO`.

### Meta etiquetas:

Nos dan información para los navegadores y buscadores de cómo esta creado la web asi como datos del mismo contenido.

Existen unas metas etiquetas bastante importantes a la hora de posicionar una página web veamos algunos:

**Meta etiqueta**: title

El titulo será visible en la parte superior del `navegador` y además es el trozo de texto que se lee en los resultados de los buscadores.

El titulo debe contener entre 40 y 80 caracteres y debemos definir fielmente el contenido de la página, es decir, un título original y que exprese lo que vas a encontrar en la página.

Su definición es:

```
<title>Hola mundo</title>
```

**Meta etiqueta**: description

Es un texto que debe formarse en no más de 250 caracteres, que trata de expresar brevemente lo que podemos encontrar en la página en modo descripción. Esta descripción es muchas veces la descripción que los buscadores muestran para cada página como resultado de busqueda.

En el caso de `GOOGLE` es el trozo de texto en negro que aparece después del título y antes de la url. Si el texto está ausente o se ha determinado que no es fiel al contenido de la web, puede cambiar y ser un trozo de texto sacado de la web por el propio buscador y que a su juicio defina mejor el contenido de la web.

Esta meta etiqueta es importante ya que no solo indicas a los buscadores que encontrar en tus páginas, sino que los usuarios se fijan en este texto de los buscadores y lo utilizan para decidir si entrar o no en la web.

Su definición es:

```
<meta name=”description” content=”Descripci&oacute;n” />
```

**Meta etiqueta**: robots

Con esta meta etiqueta podemos controlar el comportamiento del `rastreo` y las `indexación` del motor de búsqueda. La meta etiqueta `robots` se aplica a todos los motores de búsqueda. Sus valores predeterminados son `“index, follow”`, no es necesario especificarlos.
Posibles valores:

- **Noindex**: impide que la página se indexe.
- **Nofollow**: impide que Googlebot siga enlaces de esta página.
- **Nosnippet**: impide que un fragmento se muestre en los resultados de
  búsquedas.
- **Noodp**: impide que un fragmento se muestre en los resultados de
  búsqueda.
- **Noarchive**: impide que Google muestra el enlace “En cache” de una
     página.
- **Unavaiable_after:[date]**: le permite especificar una hora y fecha
  exactas en que desea detener el rastreo y la indexación de la página.
- **Noimageindex**: permite especificar que no desea que la página aparezca
  como la página de referencia de una imagen que se muestra en los
  resultados de la búsqueda de Google.

> **Nota**: esta meta etiqueta es importante y peligrosa ya que hay que tener cuidado a la hora de modificarla porque podríamos equivocarnos y poner que no indexen nuestra web o no sigan los enlaces de la misma.

Su definicion es:

```
<meta name=”robotos” content=”valores” />
```

**Etiqueta**: canonical

Esta etiqueta se creó por la necesidad, en algunos casos, tenemos varias páginas web dentro de un subdominio con un contenido casi idéntico, en caso no añadir esta etiqueta, seriamos penalizados por los buscadores por contenido duplicado.

Esta etiqueta permite decir a los buscadores que la pagina que están rastreando es la misma que otra y que deben darle la importancia a esa otra pagina que les indicamos en el canonical.

Su definición es:

```
<link rel=”canonical” href=”url_buena” />
```

### Estructura

La restructuración de una web es muy importante para el posicionamiento como ya ha mencionado el compañero. Tanto a los usuarios como a los buscadores les gusta que una página web este bien estructurada y sea sencilla de leer y seguir. Por es, tenemos que tratar de dar una estructura `jerárquica` a nuestra web.

Lo más conveniente es crear una estructura en árbol a partir de un punto de origen. Existen una etiquetas que se definen `h1, h2,..,h6` que nos permite dar importancia a partes de la web. Un `h1` suele ir al comienzo de una web y es el título que mejor define el contenido de la web, suele coincidir con el título o descripción que se pongo como meta etiquetas.
Luego el `h2` está el que seguirá en importancia jerárquica, luego `h3` y así sucesivamente.

No es obligatorio el uso de todos ellos, pero si es recomendado al menos usar el `h1, h2 y h3`. También hay que tener en cuenta que podemos repetirlos tantas veces como queramos (no es recomendado repetir `h1`), los demás se pueden repetir tantas veces como se desee.

Pongamos como ejemplo para una web de concesionarios de coches en Valencia.

> Una **jerarquía** de **títulos** podría ser:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada título `H`.. debería ir seguido como mínimo de un breve texto cerca de lo indicado dentro del título.

También es importante saber, que, si se van a hacer enumeraciones de enlaces con especialidades o enumeraciones de secciones de la web, se utilicen los elementos `HTML` de lista `li` para indicar a los navegadores que esos textos son una lista de elementos.

Para verificar una correcta estructura se puede utilizar la herramienta gratuita que existe en las `webmaster Tools Google` y permite ver una página tal cual la ven los `robots` de los buscadores y ver de un modo sencillo si la estructura está clara o no.

### Contenido

Tal vez lo más importante para el posicionamiento de una web sea el contenido de la misma. Aunque esta afirmación parezca una obviedad hay que tener en cuenta que el contenido debe ser original y único, además debe estar relacionado con la temática de la web en general. Importante saber catalogar y crear tantas páginas como necesitamos para poder mostrar el contenido de nuestra web de un modo ordenado y coherente. Si la web tiene mucho contenido será una tarea importante.

Se habla mucho de los niveles de profundidad que pueda tener una web. La mayoría de expertos en `SEO` coinciden en que todo el contenido importante o prioritario de la web debería estar a no más de 4 niveles de distancia de la página inicial (raíz) para que los buscadores lo entiendan como importante y relacionado con la temática de la web.
Otro factor importante es la labor de no tener contenido duplicado o similar y las paginas cuyo contenido no sea original, es decir, cuyo contenido sea tomado de otra página web, puede llegar a ser penalizado.

Otro factor tener en cuenta, es que los buscadores les gustan las paginas dinámicas, es decir, las páginas que se actualizan que incorporan información o que corrigen información antigua u obsoleta.

### robots.txt

Un archivo robots.txt es un archivo que se encuentra en la raíz de un sitio e indica a qué partes no quieres que accedan los rastreadores de los motores de búsqueda.

Mas información donde puedes encontrar detallado su explicación:

- https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=es

### Meta tags sociales

`Og: title` es una de las metaetiquetas de gráfico abierto. `Og: ...` propiedades definen objetos en un gráfico social. Son utilizados por ejemplo por Facebook.

`Og: title` significa el título de su objeto como debería aparecer dentro de la gráfica, (vea aquí para más http://ogp.me/)

Codigo fuente:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535405/what-is-the-attribute-property-ogtitle-inside-meta-tag

Comment: Gracias amigo muy detallado, solo una duda sobre la url **canonical**  mencionaste que aquella etiquete: permite decir a los buscadores que la página que están rastreando es la misma que otra y que deben darle la importancia a esa otra página. Entonces si yo creo una url amigable de esta forma `example.com/marketing-online/email-marketing/` y la pagina original es esta: `example.com/email-marketing.php` cual debo idicar en la etiqueta **canonical** o de que forma se planteare?

Comment: De nada, espero que te haya ayudado la respuesta. Respecto a la url amigable, debes poner la version original, para que asi lo indexea los buscadores, quedaria así <link rel=”canonical” href=”http://example.com/email-marketing.php” />

Answer (score 2):

*Me parece una pregunta interesante, una pregunta que muchos a la hora de subir el sitio se nos plantea esa duda. Una lástima que no sea bienvenida.*

> Edité tu pregunta creo que el título no era el adecuado.

No podré responder a todas tus dudas no tengo mucha experiencia en SEO siempre será un misterio.

**El usó de las etiquetas H1,H2,H3?**

Lo recomendable es no utilizar más de una etiqueta `h1` en la misma página, está etiqueta se utiliza cómo el título principal del contenido no debe tener texto largo es recomendable contenido cortó en la etiqueta principal `h1` porque a lo largo su valor se pierde al contener demasiado texto.

Se dice que no existe el límite de utilizar la etiqueta `h2` por lo que he visto en otros sitios parece que tiene razón he visto más de 8 etiquetas `h2` en sitios web de los primeros lugares.

Pero es recomendable no abusar de la etiqueta `h2`, utilizar en subtítulos del contenido de la página.

La etiqueta `h3` utilizar en subencabezamientos, el resto de etiquetas no tiene límite de uso se dice que si es recomendable utilizar al menos una de cada etiqueta.

> **Nota:** Importante llevar un orden en las etiquetas **h1 h2 h3** y así sucesivamente, no un desorden así **h3 h1 h2.**